# Trigonometric Integral of variable function.

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Let for any $n \in \mathbb Z$, define a function $f_n \text { on } [0,1]$ as follows:

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}0 &\text{if} &x=0 \\
             \sin \left({\pi\over2n}\right)&\text{if}&0\lt x\le\frac{1}{n} \\
\sin \left({2\pi\over2n}\right)&\text{if}&\frac1{n}\lt x\le\frac{2}{n} \\
\\
\sin\left({3\pi\over2n}\right)&\text{if}&\frac2{n}\lt x\le\frac3{n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
\sin\left({n\pi\over2n}\right)&\text{if}&\frac{n-1}{n}\lt x\le\frac{n}{n}\\
\\
\end{cases}$$

Then, the value of $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1f_n(x)\,dx$ is?

I'm hopelessly stuck here. Ideas?

Comment: The last case seems to contain typos. At least the range for $x$ is not OK. Should it read
$$\sin\left({(n-1)\pi\over2n}\right)\quad\text{if}\;\frac{n-1}{n}\lt x\le 1$$

Comment: @gammatester yes. I'll fix that.

Comment: @gammatester updated. $\frac{n}{n}$ looks more symmetrical here though.

Comment: @gammatester that should be ${n\pi\over2n}$ and not $n-1$

Comment: If you split the integral of $f_n$ at the points $\frac{k}{n}$, you get a Riemann sum for the integral of a continuous function that you can evaluate explicitly.

Comment: @DanielFischer care to post that as an answer? I have no idea what a "Reimann sum" is supposed to be. I am googling for it now, maybe I have seen it before, just don't know it by that name.

Comment: @DanielFischer oh i just checked [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum). Up until now I just called it approximating by rectangles. :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can split the interval,

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx &= \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n} f_n(x)\,dx\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n} \sin \left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)\,dx\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}\cdot \sin \left(\frac{k\pi}{2n}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\frac{k}{n}\right),
\end{align}$$

and obtain a Riemann sum for

$$\int_0^1 \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot x\right)\,dx.$$

The limit is thus the value of that integral (which is $\frac{2}{\pi}$).

Comment: Great. Thanks. :)